# Conditional Formatting after a certain time

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight a cell to where if the event happens after 20:00:00 it will be green. The cell also includes the date.

Ex: 1/3/1950  1:18:00 PM

How would I write this out in the conditional formatting rule?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date/time value is in cell `A1`, try this:

```
=HOUR(A1) > 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to **MJH**'s answer, full answer would be this:

1. Select cells which contains time/date
2. Create new formatting rule - choose "**Use a formula to determine which cells to format**"
3. Write **MJH**'s formula:

`=HOUR(A1) > 20`